# Django Viewflow passing variables to function based view

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

Trying out a very simple test app with [viewflow.io](http://viewflow.io) using function based views rather than the built-in class based views. The intended idea is that a product is added and then approved (via two different views/ forms). There are two issues I cannot seem to work out:

1. I want to pass the `Product` to the approval view (so that the user doing the approval can see the summary of what they are meant to approve. I am not sure how to do this - I tried passing the `product_pk` via the `flow.View` in `flows.py` but this results in an error and if I leave it out then the approval view updates all records rather than the current product.
2. The `flow.If` gate in flows.py always seems to be True regardless of whether the approved field in Product has been check or not. Ideally I am hoping that the approval is recorded in the Product model rather than the process model

Probably super basic mistake/ concept I am missing - any help would be appreciated.

In **models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductProcess(Process):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True)

    def approved(self):
        return self.product.approved


class ProductTask(Task):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

In **flows.py**

```
class ProductFlow(Flow):
    process_cls = ProductProcess
    task_cls = ProductTask

    start = flow.Start(start_process).Next(this.approve)

    approve = flow.View(approve_product).Next(this.checkapproval)

    checkapproval = flow.If(cond=lambda p: p.approved()) \
        .OnFalse(this.approve) \
        .OnTrue(this.end)

    end = flow.End()
```

In **views.py**

```
@flow_start_view()
def start_process(request, activation):
    activation.prepare(request.POST or None,)
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        Product.objects.create(
            name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        )
        activation.done()
        return redirect('/test')

    return render(request, 'viewflowtest/product.html', {'activation': activation, 'form': form})

@flow_view()
def approve_product(request, activation):
    activation.prepare(request.POST or None,)
    form = ApproveProductForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        Product.objects.update(
            approved = form.cleaned_data['approved']
        )
        activation.done()
        return redirect('/test')
    return render(request, 'viewflowtest/product.html', {'activation': activation, 'form': form})
```

The form that is called is a very basic ModelForm class and the URLs are exactly as is described in the demo applications on the project GitHub pages. The template has the `{{ activation.management_form }}` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to link the product and process. So in start view, you can do

```
if form.is_valid():
    product = Product.objects.create(
        name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
        quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
    )
    activation.process.product = product
    activation.done()
```

or even better, if the ProductForm is the ModelForm

```
if form.is_valid():
    product = form.save()
    activation.process.product = product
    activation.done() # here is new process instance created and saved to db
```

So the approval view could be rewritten as::

```
@flow_view()
def approve_product(request, activation):
    activation.prepare(request.POST or None,)
    form = ApproveProductForm(request.POST or None, instance=activation.process.product)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()  # here is the approved field is updated
        activation.done()
        return redirect('/test')
    return render(request, 'viewflowtest/product.html', {'activation': activation, 'form': form})
```

In addition, you can take a look to the viewflow example with the function-based views - https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/blob/master/viewflow_customization/customization/parcel/views.py

Comment: Kickass! :) Thanks very much for the super quick answer (hopefully I will manage to work out the rest of the Viewflow without posting questions on every hurdle!) The app looks fantastic thus far BTW